# Silverlight: How do I create a scrollable horizontal list of images

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Most answers to this question say to do something like this:

```
<ListBox Margin="47,241,53,264">

    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="/ApplicationIcon.png"/>
    <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="/ApplicationIcon.png"/>
    <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="/ApplicationIcon.png"/>
    <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="/ApplicationIcon.png"/>
    <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="/ApplicationIcon.png"/>
</ListBox>
```

However this will not enable horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not setting the Visibility to the Scrollbar

```
<ListBox Margin="47,241,53,264"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    .
    .
    .
</ListBox>
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! I needed ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility set to "Visible" instead of the vertical one, but apart from that this did the trick nicely. What threw me off is that without setting this explicitly the listbox kind of scrolls horizontally, sometimes, if you try hard enough :/